# Programmatically run Catalog product flat index

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing

I have system,in there system i want to run  catalog product flat index process pragmatically. I have code is

`Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat');`
Can any one tell me that is the right code...???or have any other code.

**But i want to run the index process by indexer code "catalog_product_flat"**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat'); //the ID is 4
$process->reindexEverything();
```

Then you should be all set